# May a sequence of a random variable converge in distribution to two random variables with different distributions? How can I prove or disprove this?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I would like to know if a sequence of a random variable converge, in distribution, to two different random variables with different distributions? How can I prove or disprove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible. By definition, a sequence of random variables $\ \big\{X_n\big\}\ $ converges in distribution to $\ X\ $ if the distributions of $\ X_n\ $ converge to the distribution of $\ X\ $ at all points of continuity of the latter, and hence the limiting distribution must be unique.

Comment: Can I use the theorem on the uniqueness of limits to formally prove this statement?

Comment: Yes, but since the convergence occurs only at points of continuity of the limit you will also need to use some of the properties of distribution functions to complete the proof.  Distribution functions are right continuous and have at most a countable number of discontinuities, so any point of discontinuity  must be the limit of a  decreasing sequence of points of continuity.  This is enough to show that the limiting distribution must be uniquely determined, even at its points of discontinuity.